# cannot install Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, azure, eclipse-plugin

When I try to instal "Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse with Java" by going to Help choose install new software, it generates following error. I have asked google but couldn't find any useful post.
I have Installed Windows Azure Sdk for .NET which adds the emulator.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse with Java (by MS Open Tech)
 1.7.0.201206062138 (com.persistent.winazure.eclipseplugin.feature.feature.group 1.7.0.201206062138)
Missing requirement: WAEclipsePlugin 1.7.0.201206062138 (com.persistent.winazure.eclipseplugin 1.7.0.201206062138) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0' but it could not be found
 Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse with Java (by MS Open Tech) 1.7.0.201206062138 (com.persistent.winazure.eclipseplugin.feature.feature.group 1.7.0.201206062138)
To: com.persistent.winazure.eclipseplugin [1.7.0.201206062138]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have just released an update fixing this bug (i.e. broken support for Helios), and a few others. Invoke Eclipse's plugin update feature, or just tell Eclipse to install the plugin from http://dl.msopentech.com/eclipse.

Martin Sawicki
Principal Program Manager
Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. 
A subsidiary of Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday there were announcements about several new features in the Windows Azure Spring Release. [One of those announcements](http://blogs.technet.com/b/port25/archive/2012/06/06/a-new-milestone-for-openness-on-windows-azure.aspx) mentioned an updated Eclipse plugin, as well as sdk refreshes. Based on the error message, you may have installed updated bits for Eclipse that could be out of sync with something else that hasn't been updated yet.

During the [Meet Windows Azure](http://www.meetwindowsazure.com) event today, everything is being formally announced via webcast.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I checked it yesterday, I have installed windows azure sdk 1.7 RC but still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are random errors which just happen if there some network error. You may find similar problems and while installing the plugin however trying again mostly resolve such problem.

I just gave a quick try as setting the New Install point as "http://dl.msopentech.com/eclipse" in Eclipse as below:
[image]

And then downloaded the selected components:

[image]
The download and install went fine without any hitch so please try again and you should not have any problem as you just experiences a random trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have tried many times and it generates same error always. I have windows 7 64bits, installed java 7u4 64 bits, tested with eclipse Galileo and Helios. What do I need to do to make it works, do I need to change System variables, or have tomcat running or something which may I have missed?? thanks again.

Comment: I would like to share the solution for all that it was the eclipse, I changed to Indigo so the problem solved.

Comment: Does it means that anyone must have Indigo to get Azure SDK installed on Eclipse?

Comment: I dont exactly know why it works with Indigo (without changing any settings), I tested Helios for Java EE and Galileo for Java EE but got same error.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!! Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is a bug in the plugin's June 2012 release that it doesn't install on Helios. An update with a fix for this issue is coming up later in July.